# Angular js - directive and ajax call

Tags: angularjs, qtip

I am a new to angular and i have a question about angular ajax call.

I struggle with a service call that fires after my directive. and i can´t get it to work properly. the code works with hardcoded json-data in the controller but idont know how to setup the service/factory to my remote service.

here is my working sample with hardcoded json. 
code explained:
i have a list of item in my view and want to show an toolbox, on hover each item. i use Jquery.qtip.js to do so. 
i use an directive to show the toolbox and get the content from the controller json. (in function getcurrentbooklist just whant to do a mark in the toolboxlist where name are same.)

```
var listControllers = angular.module('listControllers', []);

listControllers.controller("StartCtrl", function ($scope) {    
    $scope.booklist = [
    { name: 'John', age: 25, gender: 'boy' },
    { name: 'Jessie', age: 30, gender: 'girl' },
    { name: 'Johanna', age: 28, gender: 'girl' },
    { name: 'Joy', age: 15, gender: 'girl' },
    { name: 'Mary', age: 28, gender: 'girl' },
    { name: 'Peter', age: 95, gender: 'boy' },
    { name: 'Sebastian', age: 50, gender: 'boy' },
    { name: 'Erika', age: 27, gender: 'girl' },
    { name: 'Patrick', age: 40, gender: 'boy' },
    { name: 'Samantha', age: 60, gender: 'girl' }
    ];

    $scope.gettooltips = function (bookid) {

        return getcurrentbooklist(bookid, $scope.booklist);
    }
});

listControllers.directive('qtip', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.qtip({
                content: {
                    text: scope.gettooltips(attrs.qtip)
                },
                position: {
                    my: 'bottom center',
                    at: 'top center'
                },
                hide: {
                    fixed: true,
                    delay: 300
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

var getcurrentbooklist = function (name, arr) {
    var rettext = "<ul>";
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (name== arr[i].name) {
            rettext += "<li>" + arr[i].name + " - mark </li>";
        } else {
            rettext += "<li>" + arr[i].name +"</li>";
        }
    }
    rettext += "</ul>";
    return rettext;
};
```

thanks

Comment: the problem is that the directive wont populate after an ajax call because the $http fires after the directive

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use the service/factory to get remote data, the call to $http returns a promise object. Please check the [$http.get docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get). The call to your further actions after the data is fetched is done when the promise resolves/fails.

Answer (score 0):

Inject your service to the directive and service will have your service calls. in controller you can define your own function to call services.

```
    var listControllers = angular.module('listControllers', []);

    listControllers.directive('qtip', ['YourService', function (YourService)  {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',                
            controller: ["$scope", "$attrs", "YourService", function ($scope, $attrs, YourService) {
               $scope.gettooltips = function (bookid) {

               return YourService.getcurrentbooklist(bookid, $scope.booklist);
             }
           }
        };
    });
```

Comment: thx! it almost solved my problem :)  but i found that one problem with this is that you get alot of ajax requests. one for each use of the directive.
is there any way to cache data, reuse it or get only one service request?

Comment: you can cache response data in client and if the data is already exist you can avoid server request. :) First you have to inject "cacheData" and use following command to store data in cache. cacheData.put('cacheKey', responseData);

Answer (score 0):

you can do write your service as below

```
 app.service(
            "myservice",
            function( $http, $q ) {
                // Return public API.
                return({
                    getdata: getdatas
                });

                function getdatas() {

                    var request = $http({
                        method: "get",
                        url: "url for calling",
                        params: {
                            action: "get"
                        }
                    });

                    return( request.then( handleSuccess, handleError ) );

                }


                function handleError( response ) {

                    if (
                        ! angular.isObject( response.data ) ||
                        ! response.data.message
                        ) {

                        return( $q.reject( "An unknown error occurred." ) );
                    }
                    // Otherwise, use expected error message.
                    return( $q.reject( response.data.message ) );
                }


                // I transform the successful response
                // from the API response payload.
                function handleSuccess( response ) {
                    return( response.data );
                }
            }
        );
```

from controller you can use service like this

```
app.controller(
            "DemoController",
            function( $scope, myservice) {
               $scope.getdata = function() {
                    myservice.getdatas()
                        .then( function( data) {
                                //process data
                            });

                };
            );
```

Comment: thx! your sample helped me alot writing service calls! but for the directive part i got the same result. it loads after the directive and wont populate my list. but maybe iam doing it wrong..